# Is upgrading to graph api > v2.8 a must?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I received an email from facebook developers:

> v2.8 Upgrade Reminder   Your App, APPNAME, is currently accessing
>   Graph API v2.8 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 18
>   April, 2019. We estimate 1 endpoint that APPNAME calls will be
>   impacted by this change and may stop working after the automatic
>   upgrade push. To ensure a smooth transition, please migrate all calls
>   to Graph API v2.9 or higher. Use the API Upgrade Tool to understand
>   exactly how this change will impact your app.

My app doing some log events using:

```
FBSDKAppEvents logEvent
```

I'm Currently not using the logs and I don't want to publish new version to the app store, just for that. so, 
can I leave it with version 2.8?

Will my app crash for using the deprecated version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test by upgrading to latest version for the tester or developer facebook account first (upgrade calls for app roles option - on the right)

Run the app with tester or developer fb account, if everything is okay, upgrade for all users (upgrade all calls - on the left)

Check account role in the 'Roles' section (below Advanced)

It is described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/

These are backend stuff, it seems client update is not usually needed.

[image]